# SOMETHING SIMPLE - display number in Label

Tags: vb.net

I want to display number 0.85 in Label when I click the button, and every time I click the button, I want it to be added on the existing value 0.85.
Like a simple counter...

I already have something that is working, but it's only working with "whole" numbers like 1,2,3...not with 0.85, etc (Sorry for my English, I don't know how to express.

Here is the code

```
Private Sub jedan_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles jedan.Click
    Count1.Text = Val(Count1.Text) + 1

End Sub

Private Sub Release1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Release1.Click
    Count1.Text = Val(Count1.Text) - 1
    r1.Text = Val(r1.Text) + 1

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
Count1.Text = CDec(Count1.Text) + 1
```

CDec should convert it to a Decimal

Comment: you're welcome. since it's working, can you please mark as the solution?

Comment: I did, Thank you once again :)

Comment: With Option Strict on (which it should be) this code will not compile.